# Entire item in StackExchange dropdown should be a link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

**Update:** the flashy new reinvented top bar implemented an improved version of this idea. It's even better than I imagined **:)**

And with that, a moderator may feel free to add [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

---

This is my opinion on the formatting of each tab of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

**Hot questions:**

- the question title (leads to the question),
- a number (I'm actually curious -  what *is* that number? Total score of answers?)(leads to the question), and
- the site the question is on (leads to the site's homepage)

  **Ideally:** I normally want to go straight to the question, and find it annoying to accidentally click on the site link instead. If I want to go to that site, I'll either look under "all sites" or click the first question I see from that site in this menu, then click the relatively huge icon in the top left. Entire div leads to the question.

**All sites:**

- items have three links, but they all lead to the site's homepage.

  **Ideally:** Entire div leads to the site's homepage.

**Inbox:**

- the site icon (leads to its homepage, which makes sense)
- link to the new comment/answer, which only spans around the question (i.e., a preview of the response is shown, but not as a link)

  **Ideally:** Entire right portion of div (everything except the icon) leads to the new comment/answer. (Icon leads to site homepage, as it does currently)

**Notifications:**

- having separate links makes sense - one to your new badge/privilege ("learn more") and one to your profile, but this also seems crammed.

  **Ideally:** Entire div leads to badge/privilege explanation page (and for badges, possibly the link to your profile ought to be in the same place as the site URL is in the "hot questions" tab - on its own line, since your profile is so easily accessible from the activity dropdown).

Comment: The number is the "hotness value," that is, how "hot" it is deemed to be (by some algorithm).

Comment: I don't know if I can come up with a good objection to this proposal, other than to ask *why*. Do you really have that much trouble finding and clicking the links to the things you're interested in? Is this an accessibility problem?

Comment: When I'm in the "Hot Questions" tab, I want to click and be taken to a question. The font is generally small, which isn't really a problem, but it makes it quite easy to miss the link, as most of the div is not clickable. It's not a necessity, but it would be relatively easy to change (on the order of adding a couple of rules to the styling, I think). So if it does get changed, it should be a low priority, but I don't think there's any harm in it, and at least one person would appreciate the change.

Comment: Dunno if it's your post that motivating the team, but they did exactly this in the new top bar.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, they sure did. A huge improvement. Thanks for the reminder!